# How to disable Intellij IDEA feature which doesn't let me enter closing character ">" in pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm new with IntelliJ and I try to put together a maven project with it. I'm a former NetBeans user which has an excellent integration with Maven.

So, I would like to create my project and setup everything. When I start enter the following It just stops according to the second sample and I can't enter the ">" character to move forward.

What is this feature and how can I disable it?

- **Intellij IDEA** version: 2017.1.2
- **OS**: Windows 10

I tried to search for it, but there is no usable information so far.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<properties> <!-- I can enter this line -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding <!-- Up to this point I can enter stuff, but there are no way to enter the ">" character -->
</properties> <!-- This will be added automatically -->
```

Comment: no problems here, what version of IJ and which OS?

Comment: Please, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is related to the, it seems [well known and always coming back](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-91975#comment=27-384169), Alt-Gr issue in JetBrains' products. The point of the issue is the next:

- there are keyboards which for some reasons accept Ctrl-Alt as AltGr and the whole keyboard layout will be messed up
- solution for me: remove all of shortcut contains Ctlr-Alt

The funny is that, I have the same keyboard at my workplace and home ([Logitech K270](http://www.logitech.com/en-roeu/product/wireless-keyboard-k270)), but at my workplace I'm using Windows 7, and it works like a charm. But home I have Windows 10 and it is messed up.

Answer (score 1):

I am on Windows 7, IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2, and I don't have the issue.

But a possible workaround would be to copy-paste `<property>`, then type `</`: it should auto-complete to `</properties>`

Check also the settings under Editor/General/Code completion.

In a true maven project with IntelliJ, just typing an element in a `pom.xml` should trigger the completion following the `pom.xml` schema.

Comment: Copy-paste works for me too. I believe, there is no such element in the xsd file, however this property is suggested by Maven.

Comment: It should detect the xsd at the beginning of your xml file. I have `<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">`

Comment: Maybe there is an internet access issue which "freezes" the completion because it tries to read that xsd?